# javascript select element

Tags: javascript

I have a select element like this

```
<select name ="cars">
  <option value="frd"> Ford </option>
  <option value="hdn"> Holden </option>
  <option value="nsn"> Nissan </option>
</select>
```

I want to set selected to "Holden" with javascript without selected by value. how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you add values? It is the right markup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**update** *after comment*

Use the following to find the option by text and select it

```
var optionlist = document.getElementById('cars').options;

for (var option = 0; option < optionlist.length; option++ )
{
  if (optionlist[option].text == 'Holden')
  {
    optionlist[option].selected = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/vQhfq/

---

***original***

When there is no value attribute specified for option elements, they assume the value to be the text.

I would suggest you use an id, so you can easily find the element.

**Html**

```
<select name ="cars" id="cars">
  <option> Ford </option>
  <option> Holden </option>
  <option> Nissan </option>
</select>
```

**javascript**

```
document.getElementById('cars').value = 'Holden';
```

(*make sure you run this code, after the select element is created*)

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Pwb5u/

Comment: +1 for suggest using an ID. The rest of the answer does answer the question, but the correct solution is to use an ID value.

Comment: He can also use the method .getElementsByName("cars"). If this element within a form it is also possible to use form syntax.

Comment: @Gaby its great. but unfortunately I have values in code but I want to access by its text. Sorry I couldn't describe question very well

Comment: @qwera, i am still not sure what you try to do. What do you mean you have values in code ? can you give a more complete example, and where you get stuck ?

Comment: @Gaby I have edited my question. Now it included values but I want to select element with text like Holdon or Nissan.

Answer (score 1):

To select the option by its text, get a reference to the select, iterate over the options looking for the one with text "Holden", then either set the select's *selectedIndex* property to the index of the option, or set the option's *selected* property to true. e.g.

```
function setSelectedByText(id, text) {
  var select = document.getElementById(id);
  var options = select && select.options;
  var opt;

  for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i++)  {
    opt = options[i];
    if (opt.text == text) {
      opt.selected = true;
      // or
      select.selectedIndex = i;
    } 
  }
}
```

For the record, the value of the select element is the value of the selected option, or, if the selected option has no value, it's text. However, IE gets it wrong and returns "" if the option has no value.

Also, if you don't want to use getElementById, you can use:

```
var select = document.formName.selectName;
```

Noting that the select element must have a name to be successful (i.e. for its value to be returned when the form it's in is submitted).